# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.2.125 The sender has exceeded the maximum number of messages they are allowed to send

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have written a automated Java selenium script to send an image via mail. I scheduled it in Windows and it was successfully running for more than 1 month. Now when the script gets executed I'm getting below error.

```
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.2.125 The sender has exceeded the maximum number of messages they are allowed to send via client submission either per minute or per day. [SG2PR03MB3115.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com]

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1100)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at zabbix_new.mail(zabbix_new.java:167)
... 1 more
```

Can any one please help me on this.

Thanks,
Divya

Comment: Error clearly tells you where the problem is: `The sender has exceeded the maximum number of messages they are allowed to send via client submission either per minute or per day. [SG2PR03MB3115.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com]` Consider checking have numbers of mails being sent or stronger restrictions implemented by SMTP admin.

Comment: Thanks. Is any other way alternative way to implement the same. Because our process gets stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft office 365 only allow 10,000 mail per day and 30 mail per minute.
[Microsoft Exchange send limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits?redirectedfrom=MSDN#sending-limits-1)

I have implement a solution for this issue in our system.

Rule #1: You should only send upto 30 mails in a minute.

Rule #2: Daily limit 10,000 can be managed by using multiple sender mail account. 
You can log send mail number somewhere to check whether it reaches limit. else you can switch to other account when this particular exception caught.